# Global variable "x" does not exist, Processing 3.2.3

Tags: java, processing

I was beginning with coding in Processing when I encountered an error which I can't find a solution for.

Code:

```
void setup(){
  size(640,360);
}

int scl = 20;

void draw(){
  background(250);
  drawGrid(scl);
  makeObject(0,0,20,20);
}

void drawGrid(float size){
  for(int v=0;v<640/20;v++){
    for(int h=0;h<360/20;h++){
      rect(h*size,v*size,size,size);
    }
  }
}

void makeObject(int obX,int obY,int obHeight,int obWidth){
  this.x = obX;
  this.y = obY;
  this.obH = obHeight;
  this.obW = obWidth;

  rect(this.x,this.y,this.obH,this.obW);
}
```

The error is: 'The global variable "x" does not exist', 'The global variable "y" does not exist' and so forth.
Please help

Comment: Does your class have those variables defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your error says it all: you're using an `x` variable, but you're never declaring it.

Let me guess: you're coming from a JavaScript background? Your `makeObject()` function looks like a JavaScript constructor, but that's not at all how objects work in Java.

In Java, you have to define a `class` and then declare the variable you're going to use. Like this:

```
class MyObject{
   float x;
   float y;
   float obH;
   float obW;

   public MyObject(float obX, float obY, float obHeight, float obWidth){
      this.x = obX;
      this.y = obY;
      this.obH = obHeight;
      this.obW = obWidth;
   }
}
```

You could then add functions to that class, such as a `drawMe()` function that uses those variables to draw a rectangle.

However, I'm not sure why you're trying to create an object at all, since you never actually use the object you create. You could just use the parameters directly:

```
void makeObject(int obX,int obY,int obHeight,int obWidth){
  rect(obX, obY, obHeight, obWidth);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond. I was planning on making a very simple game and I thought that making a reusable function would make it all a lot easier.

Comment: @Mr.Dude__ You've got the right idea: you should use reusable functions and objects whenever you can. But your syntax was just off. You were halfway between a class and a function. You just need to choose one. :p

Comment: Btw you were also right about me coming from a Javascript background and again, thank you for responding because I now understand how classes and objects work.